# Change editingStyle background color and label for cells in tableView

Tags: swift, tableview, cell, swift4

I have a tableview where I'm trying to implement a swipe-to-delete action.

I'm using swift 4 and Xcode 9.

So far I have the next code which allows me to show a delete label when swipe:

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, commit editingStyle: UITableViewCellEditingStyle, forRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
    switch editingStyle {
    case .delete:
        print("deleting row")

    default:
        return
    }
}
```

So far so good, now I'd like to change the background red color to another one and if it's also possible i'd like to show an icon instead of a label.

I'm trying this code I've seen for Swift 4 but it's complaining when creating the button:

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, editActionsForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> [UITableViewRowAction]? {
    let deleteButton = UITableViewRowAction(style: .default, title: "Delete") { (action, indexPath) in
        self.tableView.dataSource?.tableView!(self.tableView, commit: .delete, forRowAt: indexPath)
        return
    }
    deleteButton.backgroundColor = UIColor.black
    return [deleteButton]
}
```

It gives this error -> Ambiguous reference to member 'tableView(_:numberOfRowsInSection:)'

I don't know if I'm trying the good way to edit, or if it's not editable at all on swift 4.

Any help is appreciated,

Thanks!

Comment: Do you use function canEditRowAt? If not, use and return true

Comment: "self.tableView.dataSource?.tableView!(self.tableView, commit: .delete, forRowAt: indexPath)
 return   " can you tell me about this lines

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I am using Xcode 9.2 and swift 4. Used same code but with no errors. Full code is here. That may help to you.

```
    import UIKit

    class ViewController: UIViewController, UITableViewDataSource, UITableViewDelegate {

    var tableView: UITableView!

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        tableView = UITableView(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: self.view.frame.width, height: self.view.frame.height), style: .plain)

        tableView.dataSource = self
        tableView.delegate = self

        self.view.addSubview(tableView)
    }

    func numberOfSections(in tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
        return 1
    }

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return 3
    }

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        let cell = UITableViewCell(style: .default, reuseIdentifier: "Cell")
        cell.textLabel?.text = "Lalala"
        return cell
    }

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, canEditRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> Bool {
        return true
    }

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, commit editingStyle: UITableViewCellEditingStyle, forRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
        switch editingStyle {
        case .delete:
            print("deleting row")

        default:
            return
        }
    }

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, editActionsForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> [UITableViewRowAction]? {
        let deleteButton = UITableViewRowAction(style: .default, title: "Delete") { (action, indexPath) in
            self.tableView.dataSource?.tableView!(self.tableView, commit: .delete, forRowAt: indexPath)
            return
        }
        deleteButton.backgroundColor = UIColor.black
        return [deleteButton]
    }
}
```

Comment: That did it, thanks! I don't actually needed to add numberOfSections and canEditRowAt, and i had to remove editingStyle, just added "editActionsForRowAt"

Answer (score 1):

I was tried like this ,may be this will help you.

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, editActionsForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> [UITableViewRowAction]? {

            let deleteAction = UITableViewRowAction(style: .default, title: "Delete") { (action, indexPath) in

                print("Did tap the button")
                self.deleteSession(sessionId: self.tableModel[indexPath.row].Id)
                print("the session id is '\(self.tableModel[indexPath.row].Id)'")
                self.tableModel.remove(at: indexPath.row)
                print("\(indexPath.row)")
                tableView.deleteRows(at: [indexPath], with: .fade)
                print("\([indexPath])")
        self.medilogTableView.reloadData()

            }
    deleteAction.backgroundColor = UIColor.red
            //deleteAction.backgroundColor = UIColor(patternImage: UIImage(named: "delete_button")!)
            //renameAction.backgroundColor = UIColor(red: 0.298, green: 0.851, blue: 0.3922, alpha: 1.0)
            return [deleteAction]
        }

        medilogTableView is name of the table
```

Answer (score 0):

You must implement your edit code inside the "in" callback :

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, editActionsForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> [UITableViewRowAction]? {
    let deleteButton = UITableViewRowAction(style: .default, title: "Delete") { (action, indexPath) in
        // here implement your delete code
    }

    deleteButton.backgroundColor = .blue
    return [deleteButton]
}
```

Sample of implementation for your "delete code" :

```
self.tableView.beginUpdates()
self.data.remove(at: indexPath.row)
self.tableView.deleteRows(at: [indexPath], with: .left)
self.tableView.endUpdates()
```